# Automatically Table Insert

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, insert

I have a problem with inserting data into a table using a stored procedure. I have to use this procedures and they where written by an other programmer.

with this procedure I can insert orders into the database. I deliver several attributes to the procedure and everything is fine. in the orders-table there is a column with the costumer ID.

When I insert a new row into the orders table the shipping adress is overwritten by data from the customer-table. The procedure doesn't make anything like this. If I write a manual insert into the orders-table my shipping adress is accepted.

Is it possible, that there are hidden procedures wich automatically get the customer information when inserting a new order?

```
USE [EHS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_INTERNETAUFTRAGE]    Script Date: 10/07/2013 12:21:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_INTERNETAUFTRAGE]
@Akcija int = 1,
/*
Many more attributes
*/      
@p6 money = NULL,
@rezultat int = 0 OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @brojac int
SET @brojac = 0
DECLARE @TypName nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @firmC int
DECLARE @gespert bit
DECLARE @letzeAufNr int
DECLARE @letzeRechNr int
SET @gespert=0
SELECT @TypName = [Name], @letzeAufNr = letzteAufNr, @gespert = gesperrt FROM dbo.T_letzteAufNr WHERE Typ=@Typ AND Jahr=Year(GETDATE())

SET @firmC=(@Typ-1)/10
IF (@firmC=3)
BEGIN
    SET @firmC=4
END
IF (@Akcija=1)
   BEGIN
    IF (@gespert=0)
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @AufNrNew nvarchar(10)
                DECLARE @AufNrN int
                SET @AufNrNew =CAST(@Typ AS nvarchar(2)) + Right(CAST(Year(GETDATE()) AS nvarchar(4)), 2) + Right('0000' + CAST((@letzeAufNr + 1) as nvarchar(10)), 5) 
                SET @AufNrN = CAST(@AufNrNew AS int)

                PRINT @RechOrt

                INSERT INTO dbo.T_Internetaufträge (rows) VALUES 
                                       (values)

                INSERT INTO dbo.T_Internetaufträge_Historie (rows) VALUES 
                                       (values)

                UPDATE dbo.T_letzteAufNr SET letzteAufNr=(@letzeAufNr+1) WHERE Typ=@Typ AND Jahr=Year(GETDATE())
            -- UPDATE dbo.T_letzteAufNr SET gesperrt=0 WHERE Typ=@Typ AND Jahr=Year(GETDATE()) 


               UPDATE T_Kunden SET FirmaCust=FirmaCust |@firmC WHERE KuNr=@KuNr


                SET @rezultat=@AufNrN
                return @rezultat
    END ELSE BEGIN
            SET @rezultat=-3 /*GESPERT*/
            return -3
        END
   END ELSE BEGIN 
      PRINT 'UPDATE'
      UPDATE dbo.T_Internetaufträge SET rows=values /* many more */ WHERE AufNr = @AufNr
      INSERT INTO dbo.T_Internetaufträge_Historie (rows) VALUES 
                                       (values)
END
SET @rezultat = 0
 return 0
END
```

Comment: Any insert trigger on the orders table?

Comment: Could be a trigger written on the database. These are kind of procedures which can be indicated to run automatically on DB events such as Insert/Update/Delete

Comment: Microsof SQL Management Studio shows no trigger in this Database.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the code of the Stored Procedure here?

Comment: I haven't looked at the stored procedure code at all but your phrase "Management Studio shows no trigger in this Database." makes me think you might be looking in the wrong place. The trigger would appear upon expanding the table. Database Triggers are different things.

Comment: OK the table itself shows also no triggers. I google for ORM. Is this maybe a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a trigger in an other table.